# Matching x,y,z,2

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a list of integers; I would like to replace anything of the form $x,y,z,2$ in such a list with $x+1, y+1, 0, 0$. The problem is that the $2$ may appear at the front, or in the first three elements, of the sequence (in which case I want to just pretend that the missing leading elements are zero), so I'm trying to use optional pattern values to deal with that. Here is what I've tried (with a different pattern output just to figure out what is going on)

```
{0, 1, 1, 2} /. {x___, a_: 0, b_: 0, c_: 0, 2, y___} :> {x, a, b, c}
    {{}, 0, 1, 1} (* this is what I'd expect. x matches to the null string *)
{1, 1, 2} /. {x___, a_: 0, b_: 0, c_: 0, 2, y___} :> {x, a, b, c}
    {{}, 1, 1, 0} (* I would have expected a=0 and b=c=1 *)
{1, 2} /. {x___, a_: 0, b_: 0, c_: 0, 2, y___} :> {{x}, a, b, c}
    {{}, 1, 0, 0} (* I would have expected a=b=0, c=1 *)
{2} /. {x___, a_: 0, b_: 0, c_: 0, 2, y___} :> {{x}, a, b, c}
    {{}, 0, 0, 0} (* This matched as I would expect *)
```

Clearly I'm misunderstanding how this pattern works. Can someone enlighten me?

I would really like to know not only what the right way to do this is, but also why what I tried did not work. I've read the section in Shifrin's book on patterns; are there other good resources to understand how patterns work?

Comment: The patterns are doing exactly what they should. It's not clear what you're trying to do. Is it that you have some sequence of integers that can be length 1 to length N, and within that sequence, if the sub-sequence `x_,y_,z_,2` is found, it is to be replaced by `x+1,y+1,0,0` for all such sub-sequences? And if a 2 occurs before the 4th position is the list to be grown to the left, or the replacement truncated? What about overlaps, e.g. `1,3,4,2,1,2,3,4` - how are those to be handled? I think the OP needs more details...

Comment: @rasher I meant for the list to be grown to the left; sorry, I thought that was clear. As for overlaps, it turns out in my application that they don't matter --- that is, whether they are done sequentially or simultaneously you will eventually get the same result (I am intending to use ReplaceAll once I get this working).

Answer (score 2):

The misunderstanding as far as I can tell lies in the order in which missing patterns are filled when using [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html) (`pattern : value`). Why does *Mathematica* fill the missing items from left to right rather than right to left?

It becomes quite clear if you think about how `Optional` is meant to be used. In *Mathematica* `Optional` is used to provide default values for function arguments:

```
f[x_: 0, y_: 0, z_: 0] := {z, y, z}
f // DownValues
```

> `{HoldPattern[f[x_ : 0, y_ : 0, z_ : 0]] :> {x, y, z}}`

`DownValues` shows us how *Mathematica* represents a function - a function in *Mathematica* is nothing but a rule. You can imagine replacing `f` with `List` (`{}`) in which case this function is very similar to your rule. Now imagine that if you wrote `f[1,2]` this would result in `{0,1,2}` - this would be counterintuitive to most people. We've left out not the first argument but the last, i.e. we expect *Mathematica* to use the provided arguments to fill in the blanks from left to right, not right to left.

I suggest using several patterns to solve your problem:

```
rules = {
   {x___, a_, b_, c_, 2, y___} :> {x, a, b, c},
   {b_, c_, 2, y___} :> {0, b, c},
   {c_, 2, y___} :> {0, 0, c},
   {2, y___} :> {0, 0, 0}
   };
{0, 1, 1, 2} /. rules
(* {0, 1, 1} *)
{1, 1, 2} /. rules
(* {0, 1, 1} *)
{1, 2} /. rules
(* {0, 0, 1} *)
```

Comment: I think there are some typos in your post - check your example and results...

Comment: @rasher yes, thanks. I only found one typo so if you see any more please elaborate.

Comment: I understand your point about functions being represented as rules. But is there a reason other than "we chose to do it that way" for filling from right to left, which is to me counterintuitive? I thought about using multiple rules, but figured there had to be a better way.

Comment: @rasher Oh, I see. It's totally the way you'd expect it to work for functions.